# finding the largest gcd while loop problems

Tags: c, while-loop

I am doing problem 3 in Project Euler in finding the largest gcd. I am supposed to find the gcd for 600851475143m, but I want to find it with a smaller number before I do so. Here's the link to the problem, I'm writing this in C.

http://projecteuler.net/problem=3

I am having problems with my while loop. My algorithm is the is to have an increasing number (i) keep dividing the given number if and only if the remainder is zero. The given number decrease as it gets divided. If i and the is equal to the given number, then i is the largest GCD.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
int origNumber = 13195;
int i = 2;
while(origNumber / i != 1 && origNumber % i != 0)   
{

    if(origNumber % i == 0)
    {
        origNumber = origNumber / i;

    }
    if(origNumber == i)
        break;



    i++;

    printf("origNumber = %d i = %d\n", origNumber, i);
}




}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem that you are having?

Comment: The Project Euler website is pretty clear on publishing solutions - it is actively discouraged. http://projecteuler.net/about

Answer (score 0):

The while loop is exiting early because of

```
while (origNumber / i != 1  && origNumber % i != 0)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`origNumber % i != 0`  will become false when origNumber is not divisible by i (which will likely happen before all divisors are found.

Change the loop statement to-:

```
while ((origNumber / i) != 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int origNumber = 13195;
    int i = 2;
    while(i*i<origNumber){
        int isFactor = 0;
        while(origNumber % i == 0)
            isFactor = origNumber = origNumber / i;

        if(isFactor)
            printf("i = %d\n", i);
        i++;
    }
    printf("origNumber = %d\n", origNumber);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this code will work, just you need to change "int origNumber" to "unsigned long long int origNumber" to use with large orignumbers like problem 3's number.

Comment: @rcpayan `"I want to find it with a smaller number before I do so."`

Comment: Thanks. Can someone explain to me the changes. SO I could understand the algorithm? Im only doing this so I could learn programming alot better.

Comment: @user1217522 `if(origNumber % i == 0){ origNumber = origNumber / i; }`  it is a need to repeat this part.